# What is an "identifier associated by name lookup"?

Tags: c++, templates

So I was reading this para from C++ standard

> **14.6.2.2 [temp.dep.expr]/3**
>
> An id-expression is type-dependent if it contains
>
> - an identifier associated by name lookup with one or more declarations    declared with a dependent type,
> - ...

Can anyone explain what exactly the term means "**an identifier associated by name lookup**" ? , is it talking about ADL or something?

Comment: What section is that in?

Comment: @tadman 14.6.2.2 [temp.dep.expr]/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means an identifier that, after name lookup has been performed, is now associated with one or more declarations of that name. Think of it as a one-to-many map of a name to a set of declarations that it could be referring to.  When there's more than one associated declaration (e.g. function overloads), overload resolution is performed only after name lookup (and association) has been performed.

Now, as for what you quoted. A dependent type means a type that depends on the *current* template instantiation. So, for example, if we have

```
template<class T> struct A {
    A<T> a1; // A<T> is a dependent type
    A<T*> a2; // A<T*> is not a dependent type
};
```

In the example above, the reason `A<T>` *is* dependent is because it refers to the current instantiation of the template class. But `A<T*>` refers to a different instantiation—a whole other class.

So your quote basically goes to say that if you have an identifier in your template code that's associated with some declaration using a dependent type, then the *id-expression* containing it is type-dependent itself. That is, it refers to type(s) referring to the current instantiation.

Comment: I would love too see an example **exactly** depicting line "an identifier associated by name lookup with **one or more declarations declared with a dependent type**" . Thanks a lot :)

Comment: or just function call (global one, not overloaded) having argument dependent on class template parameter would do? . Also can there be non-function examples? Thanks

Comment: @AngelusMortis See edit. Let me know if something's missing.